# footer in html5

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am trying to create a footer which spans the width of the screen. It was nested in the  body tag (centered by using margin left/right auto) which had a width of 825px so I took it out and nested under the html tag, thereby removing the width constraint.

What it looks like now though is that the footer element is aligned with the centered body tag at the bottom left. I'd like it to start at the very left hand of the screen.

What must I do to have the footer element span the full width of the screen going left to right?

Comment: CSS and markup would be nice.

Comment: Aside: While it may technically be possible to get away with content outside of the body (when a body is included) I would not recommend it. Instead, you should place the footer back in the body tag and use another wrapper such as a div tag to wrap all of the content that you want to center. This is one case where an extra div is worth it.

Comment: thanks for info, David, I will do this. As a novice may I ask the reasoning behind this? Also, once the div has been created how should I make it span the full screen whilst inside the body tag with a 825px width? Thanks again

Comment: You should not put anything outside the body tag and you really should not set body's width other then 100% (full width). Just use some other container inside the body to fix the width.

Comment: @DougFirr In general, HTML pages should (and will) have all content inside of a body tag. Browsers will expect this, JavaScript plugins may expect this, and you will be opening yourself to a lot of needless headaches if you try to do anything else. If you need help understanding how some of the tags introduced by HTML5 work together I recommend the following article: http://html5doctor.com/avoiding-common-html5-mistakes/

Comment: tks David I'll read over that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do  not want to have your footer outside of the HTML tag. Something like this should work.

If you have a width set on your body tag 100% will only extended to the width set on your tag. Also if you intend to use HTML5 I suggest using the `<footer></footer>` tag. Keep in mind though that HTML5 needs hacks to work on older browsers.

```
<style type="text/css">

body {/*use this to declare font-family and other common attributes */}
#header {width:825px;height:200px;margin:0 auto 0 auto}/*or whatever your dimensions are*/
#main-content-wrapper {width:825px;margin:0 auto 0 auto;}
#footer {width:100%;}


</style>

<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<head>

<body>

<div id="header"></div>

<div id="main-content-wrapper"></div>

<div id="footer"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks but I did try that and the footer only spanned the width of the containing element - the body, which had a width of 825px. I'd like the footer to span the width of the entire screen

Comment: Is there a reason the body is set to 825px? You shouldn't need a dimension on the body tag. Instead try creating a content-div with a width of 825px. This will act as your body. I will adjust my CSS to show what I mean.

Comment: @DougFirr this example will do what you want. Kris does not provide width in the body declaration, but rather in the `#header` and `#main-content-wrapper`. The point of the example is that you do NOT give the body element that 825px. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
body, footer { 
    width:100%; 
}

#main {
    width: 825px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

<body>
    <div id="main">
        /* Your page content */
    </div>
    <footer>
        /* Your footer content */
    </footer>
</body>
```

And I totally agree with @Yuri's comment to your post: Stay with the specification, don't put tags outside `<body>` or even `<html>`. Event if most browsers may be tolerant, it probably will be rendered incorrectly by some.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I fully get what you mean. But I think this might help you.

CSS:

```
body, footer{
width:100%;
}
```

with that you set the span (width) of footer and body to the width of the screen.

Comment: Hi. Thanks but yes I have set the width of the footer to 100%. The problem is that I want the footer 100% but the body 825px. Despite me taking the footer out the body the screen shows it looks like it is still inside of it, being aligned to it at the bottom left (i.e. the footer spans the screen starting about a quarter of the way in from the left - it's the gap between the very left of the screen and where the footer starts that I'm trying to remove

Comment: It would be preferable for us to see your html than for you to explain the behavior. Thanks!

Comment: Keep the footer in the body. Both on 100%. Add your content-container with 825px width and margin 0 auto. Then the footer has full width and your content 825px. Don't put elements out of the body.